# Planning to downgrade a brand new macmini to 10.6. How do I recover to mavericks if things go wrong?

Tags: mac-mini, recovery

I have a brand new macmini. It comes with mavericks and I haven't booted the machine yet. I know for certain that I will erase mavericks and install 10.6. However, if things go wrong, I would like to be able to reinstall mavericks. and restore the situation as it was as out of the shop. What do I have to do in order to achieve this ?

Comment: the new mac mini's might not support Snow Leopard.

Comment: @Mark ok so if I want a version as low as possible, how can I do that? I need to build and target old platforms. It's a build machine

Answer (score 2):

No you won't be able to install Snow Leopard, it's not compatible.

But you'll be able to build app that a compatible with older OS X from XCode. But you won't be able to test it's behaviour on older platform from this mac. You'll need older macs.

Comment: I'm not using xcode, nor I want to. We have our runtime that is general and compiled from makefiles.

Comment: This should not change a lot, you can still compile to target older OSX.

Comment: Do you have information about how to do this without using XCode magic automated project layouting and tricks? Some special flag maybe? I currently installed command line utils for XCode and XCode 5.

Comment: @StefanoBorini that is off topic for here, try StackOverflow but you should look in the Apple docs first - the part you need is the SDK https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i

Answer (score 1):

Chances are 10.6 won't work on your Mac Mini. As this hardware didn't exist when 10.6 was the main OS X version it probably doesn't have the right drivers for your hardware.